# Visual Studio 2015 Community -> cpprestsdk nuget package

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nuget

It's my first time. I have a problem with Visual Studio 2015.
I want to use the library [cpp REST SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/).
My problem is:

When I install the package using the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio, everything is ok and the package is installed.
But, when, in my code, I want to include :

```
#include <cpprest\http_client.h>
```

Intellisense tell me that it can not open the source file.

My Conclusion is: 
My package is installed but I can't use the library...

Comment: Find the expected files in your file system. Then add that directory to the include path for your project.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I have added my include, Intelisense detected the files, it's working but when I compile my app, I have a lot of error :             http://prntscr.com/b1e0eh the screenshot

Comment: Start a new question, include the errors as text.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed it using the Nuget Package Manager, then wait for some time to get it fully installed.

The last line after the full installation should look like this:

```
End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.<PerformActionImplAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
========== Finished ==========
```

After that the files will be included automatically. If you are still facing this issue, you can manually add the include path in Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C++ -> Additional Include Directories

The path will look like:

> C:\Users\ComputerName\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project\packages\cpprestsdk.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.7.0\build\native\include